# Should I sell my Elder Scrolls?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have completed the Dawguard quests and now the priest wants my Elder Scrolls.

Should I sell them to him or are they of any use in the main quest ? I am up to recruiting for the Blades.

Comment: @Namfuak sums the quest dependency aspects up pretty well. However, I would still consider that the Elder Scrolls are unique objects of great mystery, while money is more than abundant. I'd consider keeping them.

Answer (score 7):

Only

> [Elder Scroll: *Dragon*](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Elder_Scroll_(Dragon))

is used for the main quest, the others can be safely sold. [Dexion](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dexion_Evicus) will only buy

> *Blood* and *Sun*

anyway though, so you are fine to sell whatever he's offering to buy.